# laptop usb mouse freezing

Tags: windows-7, laptop, usb, mouse

My usb mouse has been working great with my laptop. A fews days ago I plugged an iphone to the usb port for charging and since then the mouse has been acting weird. It stops working for a few seconds and then starts working again. It's like when you're playing a high definition video game and once in a while the image freezes and after a short interruption things keep running as normal. The mouse is acting similarly. Sometimes the pointer freezes completely. In this case I use the laptop mouse pad for a few seconds to move the pointer and the mouse starts working again. I tried windows 7 toubleshooter but didn't help. the mouse works fine on other computers and other mouses work fine on my laptop, so the problem should be with driver/software. How can I go about fixing this?

Thansk.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It's likely either a chipset issue or a firmware/driver issue.

I recommend checking whether your drivers are out of date first,

Download [Driver Booster](https://store.iobit.com/order/product.php?PRODS=4604733&QTY=1) PRO (trial) or use the free edition.

Let it scan.

Check to see if your usb drivers need updating.. If so then update. 
Reboot and see if your problem appears again.

If it does appear again, I'd like you to go to your laptop manufacturer's support page, look up your particular laptop model number and see if there are any firmware updates.

If there are firmware updates.. install them and reboot.

If the problem still persists then there is a chance you damaged the usb port itself.. check it with a flashlight for any signs of bending/warping.

Does this only occur if you plugin your mouse or does it happen with anything that is plugged into that particular port?

Comment: Something new is happening. Sometimes all of a sudden a message appears saying the device can not be recognized. I think you're right, this is a hardware problem, maybe a faulty connection or wire.

Comment: @akumaburn while genuine recommendations are appreciated, embedding affiliate links through URL shorteners and posing them as regular answers is not acceptable and is considered spamming. Please refrain from this behavior in the future. I have edited the link to be a regular link.

Comment: @nhinkle So passing along the 40-50% discount from my links is unacceptable?

Comment: @Akumaburn that's still spamming. You could provide a regular link, and then separately have a discount link that is clearly labeled as being an affiliate link that you personally benefit from. See our [expected behavior regarding self promotion](http://superuser.com/help/behavior).

Comment: @nhinkle Isn't against the rules to down vote an answer based on something like this?

Comment: @Akumaburn of course not. Anybody can downvote for any reason they want to. In fact it's quite common to downvote posts that look like spam - like this one.

Comment: @nhinkle Democracy tends to fail in the search for truth.

Comment: @Akumaburn I would counter that the voting system is doing a very good job at identifying posts with potential problems. Your perception of "the truth" seems to be tainted by your pursuit of personal profit under the guise of an answer.

Comment: @nhinkle Your perception is flawed then. My answer was correct. The only "potential" problem is your insistence on keeping others down. You must have some kind of massive inferiority complex that made you need to modify harmless links that completely addressed the problem at hand without any down-side to the community or the person who asked the question.

Comment: @Akumaburn this community has specific expectations regarding advertising and self-promotion. Specifically, we _require_ that you disclose any affiliation (including affiliate links) to links you post, and require that posts with such links do not comprise the majority of your contributions. If you aren't interested in abiding by those expectations, you may either choose not to participate, or may find your account suspended.

Answer (score 0):

The issue could due to software driver conflict. Try reinstalling the mouse driver software and if still the issue persists.  Try performing a clean boot on windows. Please refer the below article for steps to perform a clean boot:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929135